# .Net Maui app crashes when installed from apk but works well with debugger

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, maui

I'm trying to generate APK for my .Net Maui app to test it on the local device by installing it from a signed APK. In order to generate APK I followed this [tutorial](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/publishing-dotnet-maui-app-android). I'm moving APK File generated to Android device and installing the app but the app is not working and crashes on the splash screen. App was working well when it was used in debugging mode from visual studio.

I added this in my csproj file

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor">

<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net6.0-android;net6.0-ios;net6.0-maccatalyst</TargetFrameworks>
    <TargetFrameworks Condition="$([MSBuild]::IsOSPlatform('windows'))">$(TargetFrameworks);net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFrameworks>
    <!-- Uncomment to also build the tizen app. You will need to install tizen by following this: https://github.com/Samsung/Tizen.NET -->
    <!-- <TargetFrameworks>$(TargetFrameworks);net6.0-tizen</TargetFrameworks> -->
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>AmuMAUI</RootNamespace>
    <UseMaui>true</UseMaui>
    <SingleProject>true</SingleProject>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <EnableDefaultCssItems>false</EnableDefaultCssItems>

    <!-- Display name -->
    <ApplicationTitle>Amu</ApplicationTitle>

    <!-- App Identifier -->
    <ApplicationId>com.companyname.amumaui</ApplicationId>
    <ApplicationIdGuid>55D14972-B250-4058-A1C2-41A290336F</ApplicationIdGuid>

    <!-- Versions -->
    <ApplicationDisplayVersion>1.0</ApplicationDisplayVersion>
    <ApplicationVersion>1</ApplicationVersion>

    <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'ios'">14.2</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
    <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'maccatalyst'">14.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
    <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'android'">24.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
    <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'windows'">10.0.17763.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
    <TargetPlatformMinVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'windows'">10.0.17763.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
    <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'tizen'">6.5</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|net6.0-android|AnyCPU'">
  <EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>False</EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|net6.0-ios|AnyCPU'">
  <MtouchDebug>True</MtouchDebug>
  <BuildIpa>True</BuildIpa>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|net6.0-maccatalyst|AnyCPU'" />

<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0|AnyCPU'" />

<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Release|net6.0-ios|AnyCPU'">
  <MtouchDebug>True</MtouchDebug>
  <BuildIpa>True</BuildIpa>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Release|net6.0-android|AnyCPU'">
  <EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>False</EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Release|net6.0-maccatalyst|AnyCPU'" />

<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Release|net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0|AnyCPU'" />

<ItemGroup>
    <!-- App Icon -->
    <MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\appicon.svg" ForegroundFile="Resources\Splash\amu_splash.svg" Color="#FFFFFF" />

    <!-- Splash Screen -->
    <MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Splash\amu_splash.svg" Color="#FFFFFF" BaseSize="128,128" />

    <!-- Images -->
    <MauiImage Include="Resources\Images\*" />
    <MauiImage Update="Resources\Images\dotnet_bot.svg" BaseSize="168,208" />

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <MauiFont Include="Resources\Fonts\*" />

    <!-- Raw Assets (also remove the "Resources\Raw" prefix) -->
    <MauiAsset Include="Resources\Raw\**" LogicalName="%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <None Remove="Platforms\Android\Resources\xml\network_security_config.xml" />
  <None Remove="Resources\Fonts\Bodoni-Bd-BT.TTF" />
  <None Remove="Resources\Images\amuSplash.svg" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <MauiFont Include="wwwroot\fonts\Bodoni-Bd-BT.ttf" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Blazored.LocalStorage" Version="4.3.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Blazorise" Version="1.1.5" />
  <PackageReference Include="Blazorise.Bootstrap" Version="1.1.5" />
  <PackageReference Include="Blazorise.Components" Version="1.1.5" />
  <PackageReference Include="Blazorise.DataGrid" Version="1.1.5" />
  <PackageReference Include="Blazorise.Icons.FontAwesome" Version="1.1.5" />
  <PackageReference Include="Blazorise.Sidebar" Version="1.1.5" />
  <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json.Bson" Version="1.0.2" />
  <PackageReference Include="Plugin.LocalNotification" Version="10.1.4" />
  <PackageReference Include="Radzen.Blazor" Version="4.4.7" />
  <PackageReference Include="sqlite-net-pcl" Version="1.8.116" />
  <PackageReference Include="SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green" Version="2.1.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="SQLitePCLRaw.provider.dynamic_cdecl" Version="2.1.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="SQLitePCLRaw.provider.sqlite3" Version="2.1.0" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectReference Include="..\AmuEbUiShared\AmuUiShared.csproj" />
  <ProjectReference Include="..\AmuEbViewModels\AmuEbViewModels.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <MauiImage Include="Resources\Splash\amu_splash.svg" />
  <MauiImage Include="wwwroot\images\amulogo.svg" />
</ItemGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.Contains('-android')) and '$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
    <AndroidLinkMode>None</AndroidLinkMode>
    <AndroidLinkResources>false</AndroidLinkResources>
    <AndroidDexTool>r8</AndroidDexTool>
    <AndroidKeyStore>True</AndroidKeyStore>
    <AndroidSigningKeyStore>amu.keystore</AndroidSigningKeyStore>
    <AndroidSigningKeyAlias>key</AndroidSigningKeyAlias>
    <AndroidSigningKeyPass>mypass</AndroidSigningKeyPass>
    <AndroidSigningStorePass>mypass</AndroidSigningStorePass>
</PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

I've checked logs using logcat

```
03-25 08:28:06.710  6419  6419 D ProcessState: Binder ioctl to enable oneway spam detection failed: Invalid argument
03-25 08:28:06.777  6419  6419 D CompatibilityChangeReporter: Compat change id reported: 171979766; UID 10434; state: ENABLED
03-25 08:28:06.846  6419  6419 D nativeloader: Configuring classloader-namespace for other apk /system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.jar. target_sdk_version=31, uses_libraries=ALL, library_path=/data/app/~~-15s6o83Qaub3pCI5MhNrg==/com.companyname.amumaui-gwKbAsbO2ynCWaiorbb4Sw==/lib/arm64:/data/app/~~-15s6o83Qaub3pCI5MhNrg==/com.companyname.amumaui-gwKbAsbO2ynCWaiorbb4Sw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, permitted_path=/data:/mnt/expand:/data/user/0/com.companyname.amumaui
03-25 08:28:06.846  6419  6419 D nativeloader: Extending system_exposed_libraries: libvraudio_client.qti.so:libbinauralrenderer_wrapper.qti.so:libhoaeffects.qti.so:libQOC.qti.so:libupdateprof.qti.so:libthermalclient.qti.so:libQOC.qti.so:libdiag_system.qti.so:libqape.qti.so:liblistenjni.qti.so
03-25 08:28:06.850  6419  6419 W ziparchive: Unable to open '/data/app/~~-15s6o83Qaub3pCI5MhNrg==/com.companyname.amumaui-gwKbAsbO2ynCWaiorbb4Sw==/base.dm': No such file or directory
03-25 08:28:06.850  6419  6419 W ziparchive: Unable to open '/data/app/~~-15s6o83Qaub3pCI5MhNrg==/com.companyname.amumaui-gwKbAsbO2ynCWaiorbb4Sw==/base.dm': No such file or directory
03-25 08:28:07.150  6419  6419 D nativeloader: Configuring classloader-namespace for other apk /data/app/~~-15s6o83Qaub3pCI5MhNrg==/com.companyname.amumaui-gwKbAsbO2ynCWaiorbb4Sw==/base.apk. target_sdk_version=31, uses_libraries=, library_path=/data/app/~~-15s6o83Qaub3pCI5MhNrg==/com.companyname.amumaui-gwKbAsbO2ynCWaiorbb4Sw==/lib/arm64:/data/app/~~-15s6o83Qaub3pCI5MhNrg==/com.companyname.amumaui-gwKbAsbO2ynCWaiorbb4Sw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, permitted_path=/data:/mnt/expand:/data/user/0/com.companyname.amumaui
03-25 08:28:07.175  6419  6419 V GraphicsEnvironment: ANGLE Developer option for 'com.companyname.amumaui' set to: 'default'
03-25 08:28:07.175  6419  6419 V GraphicsEnvironment: Neither updatable production driver nor prerelease driver is supported.
03-25 08:28:07.179  6419  6419 D NetworkSecurityConfig: Using Network Security Config from resource network_security_config debugBuild: true
03-25 08:28:07.181  6419  6419 D NetworkSecurityConfig: Using Network Security Config from resource network_security_config debugBuild: true
03-25 08:28:07.188  6419  6419 D debug-app-helper: Checking if libmonodroid was unpacked to /data/app/~~-15s6o83Qaub3pCI5MhNrg==/com.companyname.amumaui-gwKbAsbO2ynCWaiorbb4Sw==/lib/arm64/libmonodroid.so
03-25 08:28:07.188  6419  6419 D debug-app-helper: Native libs extracted to /data/app/~~-15s6o83Qaub3pCI5MhNrg==/com.companyname.amumaui-gwKbAsbO2ynCWaiorbb4Sw==/lib/arm64, assuming application/android:extractNativeLibs == true
03-25 08:28:07.188  6419  6419 I debug-app-helper: Setting up for DSO lookup in app data directories
03-25 08:28:07.188  6419  6419 D debug-app-helper: Added filesystem DSO lookup location: /data/app/~~-15s6o83Qaub3pCI5MhNrg==/com.companyname.amumaui-gwKbAsbO2ynCWaiorbb4Sw==/lib/arm64
03-25 08:28:07.188  6419  6419 W debug-app-helper: Using runtime path: /data/app/~~-15s6o83Qaub3pCI5MhNrg==/com.companyname.amumaui-gwKbAsbO2ynCWaiorbb4Sw==/lib/arm64
03-25 08:28:07.188  6419  6419 W debug-app-helper: checking directory: `/data/user/0/com.companyname.amumaui/files/.__override__/lib`
03-25 08:28:07.188  6419  6419 W debug-app-helper: directory does not exist: `/data/user/0/com.companyname.amumaui/files/.__override__/lib`
03-25 08:28:07.188  6419  6419 W debug-app-helper: Checking whether Mono runtime exists at: /data/user/0/com.companyname.amumaui/files/.__override__/libmonosgen-2.0.so
03-25 08:28:07.188  6419  6419 W debug-app-helper: Checking whether Mono runtime exists at: /data/app/~~-15s6o83Qaub3pCI5MhNrg==/com.companyname.amumaui-gwKbAsbO2ynCWaiorbb4Sw==/lib/arm64/libmonosgen-2.0.so
03-25 08:28:07.188  6419  6419 I debug-app-helper: Mono runtime found at: /data/app/~~-15s6o83Qaub3pCI5MhNrg==/com.companyname.amumaui-gwKbAsbO2ynCWaiorbb4Sw==/lib/arm64/libmonosgen-2.0.so
03-25 08:28:07.190  6419  6419 W yname.amumau: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
03-25 08:28:07.193  6419  6419 I DOTNET  : JNI_OnLoad: JNI_OnLoad in pal_jni.c
03-25 08:28:07.202  6419  6419 W monodroid: Creating public update directory: `/data/user/0/com.companyname.amumaui/files/.__override__`
03-25 08:28:07.202  6419  6419 W yname.amumau: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
03-25 08:28:07.202  6419  6419 W monodroid: runtime args empty
03-25 08:28:07.205  6419  6419 F monodroid: No assemblies found in '/data/user/0/com.companyname.amumaui/files/.__override__' or '<unavailable>'. Assuming this is part of Fast Deployment. Exiting...
03-25 08:28:07.205  6419  6419 F monodroid: Make sure that all entries in the APK directory named `assemblies/` are STORED (not compressed)
03-25 08:28:07.205  6419  6419 F monodroid: If Android Gradle Plugin's minification feature is enabled, it is likely all the entries in `assemblies/` are compressed
03-25 08:28:07.206  6419  6419 F libc    : Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 6419 (yname.amumaui), pid 6419 (yname.amumaui)
03-25 08:28:07.626  6450  6450 F DEBUG   : Softversion: PD2034CF_EX_A_6.8.8
03-25 08:28:07.626  6450  6450 F DEBUG   : Time: 2023-03-25 08:28:07
03-25 08:28:07.626  6450  6450 F DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
03-25 08:28:07.626  6450  6450 F DEBUG   : Build fingerprint: 'vivo/789075/2027:12/SP1A.210812.003/compiler08021735:user/release-keys'
03-25 08:28:07.626  6450  6450 F DEBUG   : Revision: '0'
03-25 08:28:07.626  6450  6450 F DEBUG   : ABI: 'arm64'
03-25 08:28:07.626  6450  6450 F DEBUG   : Timestamp: 2023-03-25 08:28:07.281564827+0500
03-25 08:28:07.626  6450  6450 F DEBUG   : Process uptime: 0s
03-25 08:28:07.626  6450  6450 F DEBUG   : Cmdline: com.companyname.amumaui
03-25 08:28:07.626  6450  6450 F DEBUG   : pid: 6419, tid: 6419, name: yname.amumaui  >>> com.companyname.amumaui <<<
03-25 08:28:07.626  6450  6450 F DEBUG   : uid: 10434
03-25 08:28:07.626  6450  6450 F DEBUG   : signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE), fault addr --------
03-25 08:28:07.626  6450  6450 F DEBUG   : Abort message: 'No assemblies found in '/data/user/0/com.companyname.amumaui/files/.__override__' or '<unavailable>'. Assuming this is part of Fast Deployment. Exiting...'
```

I'm very new to Android development.

Comment: <EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>true</EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>

Comment: I added that in my csproj file but it is now giving me this error 

`03-16:53:14.898 16179 16179 I DOTNET  : JNI_OnLoad: JNI_OnLoad in pal_jni.c
03-24 16:53:15.073 16179 16179 W monodroid-gc: GREF GC Threshold: 46080
03-24 16:53:16.084 16179 16179 E yname.akuebmau: * Assertion at /__w/1/s/src/mono/mono/mini/aot-runtime.c:3678, condition is_ok (error)' not met, function:decode_patch, module 'Microsoft.Maui.dll.so' is unusable (GUID of dependent assembly Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat doesn't match (expected '1FC81757-8A70-4D56-93E6-8A635E2C23DE', got 'FD3821D1-CBF4-4956-B930-EA2A5379E18D')).`

Comment: <RunAOTCompilation>False</RunAOTCompilation> <PublishTrimmed>False</PublishTrimmed>